# Pop up Alert box when deadline is coming in wpf

Tags: wpf, dialog

in my wpf application I have startDate and endDate of an event, I would like to implement a Pop up Alert box to show a warning message automatically when endDate is coming (say 5 days before endDate). In the screenshot when I click **ClientDeadlines** (ItemTab header in my wpf), the alert box comes out. How can I achieve this function? Any samples are appreciate. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Is your app always running ? Do you want to display it irrelevant if your app is running or not ?

Comment: where this popup alert message should be seen ? Windows scope ? App scope ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Thanks for your quick reply. I want to display the alert message when my app is running. thanks.

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas. Hi, thanks for your reply. I want to display the alert message in one sub-heading called "Deadline" in my app, when I enter "Deadline" page, the alert message will come out.I think it's app scope. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can use the DispatcherTimer in System.Windows.Threading..

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    DateTime myDeadLine = new DateTime();
    public void InitTimer()
    {
        // Checks every minute
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((myDeadLine - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 5)
            MessageBox.Show("Your Alert Message");
    }
```

**EDIT :**
As you want to display the Alert message everytime the user clicks the ClientDeadLines Subscribe for the **SelectionChanged** event in TabControl.

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="46,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397">
 <TabItem Name="Tab1" Header="Check1">
   <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
 </TabItem>
 <TabItem Name="ClientDeadLines" Header="Check2" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
 </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And use this code behind

```
 private void TabControl_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is TabControl)
        {
            if (ClientDeadLines.IsSelected)
            {
                // Your code to check time
                int a = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried and no errors, but how can i display the alertbox while clicking the tabitem **ClientDeadlines** in my screenshot.

Comment: Do you want to display the alert message when the user clicks the **ClientDeadlines**?

Comment: Yes. Since I defined EndDate in another class (another folder), I need to get that value first and then compare it with dateTime.today. When I click **ClientDeadlines**, the alertbox comes out

Comment: Thanks very much. Your method solves my problem. If I want the alertbox show the exact days left, say "your renewal date is 5 days left", "....4 days left". How can I do that? When I try to use **if (( RenewalDate.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays = 1)**, it throws errors. I post my code as an answer below. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @DanielXu Use **RenewalDate.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 1**  You missed the '='.Please post it as an seperate question or it will be confusing.

Comment: if ((RenewalDate.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 5)
                                MessageBox.Show("Your deadline is within 5 days");
                            else if ((RenewalDate.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 4)
                                MessageBox.Show("Your deadline is 4 days left");
                            else if ((RenewalDate.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 3)
                                MessageBox.Show("Your deadline is 3 days left"); I use this code, it does not work.

Comment: @DanielXu RenewalDate should be of DateTime type.But it doesn't seem to be DateTime type.It would be good if you edit and update your question.

Comment: I post it as a new question. please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use simple Timer to run scheduled check to see if it needs to pop up alert.

```
private void InitTimer()
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    timer.Interval = 60000; // Check each minute
    timer.Tick += (o,e) => CheckForDeadlines();
    timer.Start();
}

private void CheckForDeadlines()
{
  if((DateTime.Now-MyDeadline).TotalDays <= 5)
      MessageBox.Show("Alert alert! You have a deadline in 5 days");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I got an error in the line timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckForDeadlines); say: No overload for 'CheckForDeadlines' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'. I edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: No error for your code, but how can I display the alertbox while clicking the tabitem **ClientDeadlines** in my screenshot.

Comment: @DanielXu Call the CheckForDeadlines() function when the **ClientDeadlines** is clicked.(If its a button then in the button's click event)